# Unity wait for all coroutines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm going to wait for several coroutines in another coroutine. Example code

```
private IEnumerator WaitForAllAnimations(List<ShiftedGem> shiftedGems)
{
    float duration = 3f;
    isDuringAnimation = true;

    List<Coroutine> animationCoroutines = new List<Coroutine>();

    for (int i = 0; i < shiftedGems.Count(); i++)
    {
        ShiftedGem shiftedGem = shiftedGems[i];
        Debug.Log("Add animation");
        ShiftAnimation shiftAnimation = shiftedGem.GameObject.AddComponent<ShiftAnimation>();
        yield return StartCoroutine(shiftAnimation.AnimateShift(shiftedGem.GameObject, shiftedGem.ShiftAmount, duration));

        animationCoroutines.Add(animationCoroutine);
    }

    foreach (Coroutine coroutine in animationCoroutines)
    {
        Debug.Log("Wait for coroutine");
        yield return coroutine;
    }

    Debug.Log("Animation end");
    isDuringAnimation = false;
}
```

However, it does not work as expected - the Debug.Log("Animation end") is called before AnimateShift is finished.

I've tried a simpler example:

```
IEnumerator CoroutineA(List<ShiftedGem> shiftedGems)
{
    Debug.Log("Start Coroutine A");

    yield return StartCoroutine(CoroutineB());
    Debug.Log("End Coroutine A");
}

IEnumerator CoroutineB()
{
    Debug.Log("Start Coroutine B");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    Debug.Log("End Coroutine B");
}
```

Which works fine ("End Coroutine A" is logged after "End Coroutine B").

But if I move StartCoroutine(CoroutineB()) into a loop:

```
IEnumerator CoroutineA(List<ShiftedGem> shiftedGems)
{
    Debug.Log("Start Coroutine A");
    foreach (ShiftedGem shiftedGem in shiftedGems)
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(CoroutineB());
    }
    Debug.Log("End Coroutine A");
}

IEnumerator CoroutineB()
{
    Debug.Log("Start Coroutine B");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
    Debug.Log("End Coroutine B");
}
```

Then once again - Debug.Log("End Coroutine A") is called before Debug.Log("End Coroutine B").

How should I organize my code, to be able to wait for all animationCoroutines inside the WaitForAllAnimations Coroutine?

Comment: There's an issue in your WaitForAllAnimations method where you're starting the coroutines inside the loop but waiting for them in another loop. Try to start all coroutines first, and then wait for them one by one.

Comment: @BrixxonTulabing sorry but I do not understand your proposal. I'm starting all coroutines first (in the first loop) and then trying to wait for them one by one (in the second loop). How can I do it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it seems strange a bit that you are adding an object to the list of coroutines that I don't see being assigned anywhere. Anyway, about the options:

You can use some kind of counter to count the current amount of coroutines run. Based on your last piece of code:

```cs
int _someCounter = 0;

IEnumerator CoroutineA(List<ShiftedGem> shiftedGems)
{
    Debug.Log("Start Coroutine A");
    _someCounter = 0;
    foreach (ShiftedGem shiftedGem in shiftedGems)
    {
        StartCoroutine(CoroutineB());
    }
    while(_someCounter > 0)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    Debug.Log("End Coroutine A");
}

IEnumerator CoroutineB()
{
    Debug.Log("Start Coroutine B");
    _someCounter++;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
    _someCounter--;
    Debug.Log("End Coroutine B");
}
```

However, be careful that the code above will not be stable in case running the second time until the previous call is not finished yet.

---

I think the best option with minimum changes to your existing variant will be to add a flag to your `ShiftAnimation` component to check if animation is still in progress. Based on your initial example:

```cs
private IEnumerator WaitForAllAnimations(List<ShiftedGem> shiftedGems)
{
    float duration = 3f;
    isDuringAnimation = true;

    List<ShiftAnimations> animations = new List<ShiftAnimations>();

    for (int i = 0; i < shiftedGems.Count(); i++)
    {
        ShiftedGem shiftedGem = shiftedGems[i];
        Debug.Log("Add animation");
        ShiftAnimation shiftAnimation = shiftedGem.GameObject.AddComponent<ShiftAnimation>();
        animations.Add(shiftAnimation);
        shiftAnimation.AnimateShift(shiftedGem.GameObject, shiftedGem.ShiftAmount, duration);

    }
    
    bool isAnyAnimationActive;
    do
    {
        isAnyAnimationActive = false;
        foreach (var animationIt in animations)
        {
            if(animationIt.IsAnimationActive == true)
            {
                isAnyAnimationActive = true;
                break;
            }
        }        
        
        yield return null;
    }
    while(isAnyAnimationActive == true);

    Debug.Log("Animation end");
    isDuringAnimation = false;
}
```

And in your `ShiftAnimation` component something like this:

```cs
...
bool _isAnimationActive = false;

public IsAnimationActive => _isAnimationActive;

public void AnimateShift(your parameters here)
{
    StartCoroutine(CoAnimateShift(your parameters here));
}

IEnumerator CoAnimateShift(your parameters here)
{
    _isAnimationActive = true;

    // your code here

    _isAnimationActive = false;
}
...
```

Comment: I will try this second approach, however, it seems to be overcomplicated. Is there a better pattern for such things in Unity?

Comment: I don't think it is complicated. You are just starting a pack of animations (btw, the code will not even change if there will be no coroutines inside ShiftAnimation class) and waiting until all of them are completed. It can be done in multiple ways, but you will still need to check if they are completed and wait for a while to repeat the checking.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a better way to handle asynchronous tasks in Unity, I recommend checking out the [UniTask plugin](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask). This plugin offers an easy-to-use alternative to traditional C# async/await, as well as Unity's coroutines which can be difficult to work with.

With UniTask, you can use the `WhenAll()` method to wait for multiple tasks to complete. This approach only requires that you refactor your existing coroutines as async methods, which can simplify your code and improve its readability.